# Mac MAMP mysql error 1045 (2800)

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp, mysql-error-1045

I see that this is a very common question throughout stack overflow. However, the answers to those questions have not helped much. I am still having the same errors

I am new to MySQL. I'm going off a tutorial from an e-book. 
I am trying to create a database that will have access to one administrator user.

```
CREATE DATABASE publications; 
USE publications;
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jona' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u jona -p
```

This is what I am typing into the terminal. The password I am typing is correct.

[image]

I have tried:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html and many other posts here on stackoverflow.

Like i said I am new to mysql and this is getting very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to answer to my own question with some trial and error.

I did the following:

I went to the phpMyAdmin page and created the user through there.
localhost:8888/MAMP/

[image]

I made sure is was a localhost. IDK why it worked through the GUI navigation but not the terminal.

Now when i try to enter, it is successful.

[image]